# Automapper - want case sensitive

Tags: .net, automapper

From similar questions on here I have read here that `AutoMapper` used to be case sensitive, but is now case insensitive. I want it case sensitive - can't see any way to change this, and none of the other questions Re this showed how to do it (I did look). Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `.ForMember` when creating the maps?

Comment: I don't believe I can - the maps are generated by a T4 template which just iterates over the columns. The problem I had was I had renamed a navigation propery and mistakenly given it the same name (albeit different case) as a regular property. By setting CLSCompliant(true) and promoting that warning to an error I now get a compilation error which is better than nothing. And actually now I am writing this I think I actually prefer this to having AutoMapper case sensitive. thanks Ray

Answer (score 2):

You can Refer :

DataReaderMapper should create case-insensitive mappings by default

http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/6127

you can control this in Mapper.Initialize as the answer 
[AutoMapper: Mapping between a IDataReader and DTO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973351/automapper-mapping-between-a-idatareader-and-dto-object)

another good post with examples on naming convention mappings: http://blog.ac-graphic.net/automapping-c-objects-from-one-naming-convention-to-an-other/

Answer (score 0):

The closes thing I could find is the the naming convention configurations: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#naming-conventions

At the Profile or Mapper level you can specify the source and destination naming conventions:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
  cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
});
```

Or:

```
public class OrganizationProfile : Profile 
{
  public OrganizationProfile() 
  {
    SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
    DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
    //Put your CreateMap... Etc.. here
  }
}
```