# Mapping two classes in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have two classes

```
public class foo1
{
  public int id;
  public string image_link;
  public string sale_price;
}
```

and

```
public class foo2
{
 public int Id;
 public string ImageLink;
 public string SalePrice
}
```

The property values differ only by underscore and cases. I need to map these two classes.

For now I am trying something like this and its working:

```
//var b = object of foo2
var a = new foo1{
 a.id = b.Id,
 a.image_link = b.ImageLink,
 a.sale_price = b.SalePrice
}
```

I heard of AutoMapper, but I din't have clear idea of how i am going to use that or where is the option of ignoring cases or underscores in it. or is there any better solution to it?

Comment: You could read a tutorial on AutoMapper or read the documentation, it's quite straight forward and for more complex examples, the documentation even shows how to accomplish more advanced configuration.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with your current approach? It works, doesn´t it? However an alternative would also be to create some kind of conversion-method in any of your classes or to define a user-cast.

Comment: Are you doing any of this with ASP.NET ? It's quite simple then.

Comment: Honestly I don't know anything about Automapper but I just remembered that I once saw this article, maybe it helps you decided for/against AutoMapper: http://www.uglybugger.org/software/post/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper

Comment: @HimBromBeere.yeah  my current approach is working. But can we do that in a better way.? as I can have many fields in these classes

Comment: I did automapping with Visual Studio. It works fine and i never ever want to do it another way now that i know how.

Comment: And here is a global way of mapping with underscores: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630012/automapper-mapping (globally not per profile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine and works as expected.

I would personally advise you to **not** use automapper. There are plenty explanations about *why* on the Internet, here's for example one: http://www.uglybugger.org/software/post/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper

Basically the major issue is that your code will silently fail at runtime if you rename some property on your `foo1` object without modifying your `foo2` object.

Comment: Yeah _"Don't use AutoMapper, it's easy to get wrong"_ is a bit of a stretch. Using one way or the other you need unit tests to test mapping both ways anyway, as with the manual way it's just as easy to forget a property or make a copy-paste error.

Comment: @CodeCaster Fair point, but I would say that's personal preferences. I personally always prefer (if possible) my code to not compile at all if some refactoring gone wrong, instead of expecting some unit test to fail (this doesn't prevent from writing unit tests, but I prefer my compilation to fail before even calling them).

Comment: If you forgot to map the property that you now renamed, it'll still compile. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure, that's why unit tests are still important as you noted :) But failing to rename both properties would still compile with automapper, in the other hand it wouldn't compile with manual mapping.

Comment: thanks @ken2k for your suggestion. i decided to continue with my approach .:)

Answer (score 1):

As @ken2k answer, I suggest you to don't use an object mapper.

If you want to save code you can just create a new method (or directly in the constructor) for the mapping.

```
public class foo1
{
  public int id;
  public string image_link;
  public string sale_price;

  public void map(foo2 obj)
  {
    this.id = obj.Id;
    this.image_link = obj.ImageLink;
    this.sale_price = obj.SalePrice;
  }
}
```

Then

```
//var b = object of foo2
var a = new foo1();
a.map(b);
```